# Base N To Decimal Converter

Tags: java, number-systems

#### Problem

- Implement a base N to base 10 (decimal) converter, where N is between 2 and 36 inclusive.

#### Implementation

- Am I over-complicating things in `calculateDecimalCharacterValue`?

```
public class BaseToDecimalConverter {

  public static int convertToDecimal(int base, String input) {
    if (base < 2) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (base > 36) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (input == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int length = input.length();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      int digitValue = calculateDecimalCharacterValue(input.charAt(i), base);
      sum += digitValue * Math.pow(base, length - 1 - i);
    }

    return sum;
  }

  public static int calculateDecimalCharacterValue(char c, int base) {
    if (base < 2) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (base > 36) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      int numericValue = Character.getNumericValue(c);
      if (numericValue < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      return numericValue;
    }

    if (Character.isAlphabetic(c) && base > 10) {
      int alphabetValue = Character.toUpperCase(c) - 'A' + 10;
      if (alphabetValue > base) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      return alphabetValue;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of [`Integer.parseInt(s, radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) and [`Character.digit(ch, radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-)?

Comment: @200_success I was not - those seem like some fairly useful methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's weird that you offer two public functions: a general-purpose `convertToDecimal()`, and a `calculateDecimalCharacterValue()` that does the same thing but with more restrictive validation.  The latter should be a private helper function.

You are over-complicating things by a lot: the whole thing could be accomplished with [`Integer.parseInt(s, radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-).  And — not that you would need it — `calculateDecimalCharacterValue(c, base)` could be done using [`Character.digit(ch, radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-).

Technically, you aren't converting to and from decimal (base ten).  You are parsing numbers in a base-N representation to an `int`; it just happens that `int`s are conventionally formatted in base ten when you do things like `System.out.println()`.  So, the function names aren't quite right.

You shouldn't need to use `Math.pow()`.  The usual algorithm goes like this:

```
public static int convertFromBase(int base, String input) {
    // Validation omitted here...

    int result = 0;
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        result = result * base + Character.digit(c, base);
    }
    return result;
}
```